# Why Circle is not a graph?

Tags: circles, graphing-functions

My book says that though a circle is described by the equation x$^2$+y$^2$=a$^2$ where 'a' is the radius of the circle, But it is not a graph because a vertical line crosses the circle at more than 1 point. Why is this criteria of "vertical line crossing at more than one point" used as a qualifier for a graph and What does it signify?

Comment: they mean the graph of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Given any input, a function can only return one output. However, given $x=0$, there are 2 y-values that correspond to the equation: $\pm a$ -- thus the equation does not define a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and therefore the picture of that equation in the plane is not the graph of such a function. The vertical line crossing the circle at more than one point means that given an $x$ value there are more than one $y$ values corresponding to it, which precludes it from being a function.

Answer (score 5):

I think your book is referring to the graph of a *function*. The vertical line test is typical to test this. A function can only have one output, *y*, for each unique input, *x*.

Answer (score 1):

Why is a vertical line intersecting more than one point criterion?

A function, is a relation R such that if $(x,y_{1}) \in R$ and $(x,y_{2})$ in R then it must be that $y_{1}=y_{1}$

for example on a circle, you would have points say (1,5) but also (1,-5) lying on a circle, which would contradict the defintion

Comment: Does this hold true for a parabola also , then, which has its opening face on the left or right side?or an ellipse too?

Comment: A parabola is a function yes, notice that no vertical line passes through. an ellipse again is not because a vertical line could hit two points

Comment: no I am talking about the parabola having the open face on the left or right side of the y-axis(the one symmetric along x-axis).A vertical line can pass through such a parabola intersecting at 2 points.

Comment: @deepakapoor  basically think of it like this, for any x there can be at most one associated y value. for a parabola pick and x, there is only going to be on corresponding y. If you are talking about a rotated parabola then no it is not a function